# Go server and Java client communication

Tags: java, go

How to have a communication between a go server and java client without any external libraries?

Comment: Yes, of course, they both provide TCP.

Comment: @user207421 so can i use PrintWriter in java to send info over the socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and Go, C# and Go, Go and C#, C and GO, GO and Python
All languages's communication is works.

You can build http server in Go (it is not external library)
and, You can requests and get responses in Java.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

The code above is Golang's http server example.

and, You can find more information with Java http requesting,

then you should check this information.

[JAVA HTTP REQUEST, GET/POST](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

Comment: can the same be done by using sockets instead?

Comment: Of course You can use Sockets instead of http

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are exposing a remote API for your go server (eg: a REST/HTTP API, a gRPC API, etc.) you can code the server and the client in any language you wish.

Comment: sorry i am not sure what you mean by "remote api"? I wish to use only the libraries provided by go.

Comment: I mean two different applications, one written in Go, which exposes a remote API, like an REST API. The client can be written in Java (or any other language) and can run in a different application.